# How to create build variants in Flutter Android so that each build variants have different app id?

Tags: android, flutter, build-variant

I need to have 3 different APKs (dev, UAT, prod), each targetting different Firebase database. But on each Firebase project, I need to supply a permanent app id. That means I need to have 3 build variants that each deploying APK with different app id. But on Android Studio, I seem can't find such a way to build variants for Flutter for this purpose (the build variants section is empty).

What I'm looking for is not [just a different entry point and different constants](https://medium.com/meeve/build-variants-in-flutter-for-multiple-backend-environments-7e139128949b), but different app id altogether. From what I gather, changing app name and app id in Flutter requires 6-steps [like this](https://medium.com/@skyblazar.cc/how-to-change-the-package-name-of-your-flutter-app-4529e6e6e6fc). I don't think doing these 6-steps each time I want to change build scope is an efficient and correct way to handle this.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @YacineBelarbi I have, but it's an external solution rather than internal Android Studio/Flutter solution. I use git to have one base branch, then create 3 branches out of that base branch. Each of the branches only differs in the app id data. If I want to compile a different version, I need to activate a different branch first.

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter, you should select build flavors instead of build variants (combination of build flavor and build type). `Flutter run` has a `--flavor` option, but not `buildType`.

### **Specify build flavors:**

In `build.gradle` below `defaultConfig {}`:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug" // Optional, you don't need to create a separate applicationId for debug.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        qa {
            applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
        }
        prod {
        }
    }
}
```

### **Run your Flutter app with specific build flavor:**

- **On the command line:** use `flutter run --flavor flavorName`, or
- **In Android Studio**: Run/debug configuration Drop Down → Edit Configuration... → `Additional run args:` → Add `--flavor dev` or `--flavor qa` or `--flavor prod`

Confirm the applicationId has changed. I use [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) for this:

- Add `package_info_plus: ^1.0.4` to `pubspec.yaml`
- Add the code somewhere:

```dart
  PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((PackageInfo packageInfo) {
    print("Package name: ${packageInfo.packageName}");
  });
```

- The **packageName** will have both the build flavor and build type. In my case, because of `applicationIdSuffix` in both `buildTypes` and `productFlavors`, `com.example.dev.debug`. You could remove `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` if you don't need/ want it.

Now we can have separate build flavor directories with their own `google-services.json`.

Comment: Where do you define, which flavor uses which buildType? Or is that not necessary?