# Flutter - .apk from 'flutter build apk' installs on my previously installed app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

I made different branches from my master branch and changed minor things in each branch.
now I want to be able to install all of them separately on my emulator and my actual device.
I don't really know what distinguishes two flutter code bases, so I could change it in these branches.
Now, my problem is that when I run this command, and install the apk, it re-installs the previous app, like the new apk is an update to the previous one. I don't want that.
I want to be able to compare all of them in one device.

Comment: I think it is not possible, because you should change also the app id that on android is the package

Comment: There are [some things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter) you need to change in your android project of each branch to define it as a separate app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change package name in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create build variants in Flutter Android so that each build variants have different app id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666045/how-to-create-build-variants-in-flutter-android-so-that-each-build-variants-have)

Answer (score 0):

you can only have one app with a unique package name like com.company.myappname .... installed on your device.

if you want to install 2 different versions of it, you have to set 2 different package names in each branch.

But keep in mind, by changing your package name... you have to recreate a keystore file for the new one ... or a new firebase push configuration ... and so on

I use `dart-defines` to set the package name in build.gradle dynamically